# Can a service request for permission in Android M?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I figured that in M requestPermissions() can only be called by an Activity class. I have an app that has no UI screen. It runs as a background service. Does this mean that I have to put a spinner screen if checkSelfPermissions returns denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an app that has no UI screen.

Then it will never run, unless it is preinstalled on an Android device or custom ROM, or it is a plugin to some other app. Otherwise, your app will remain in the stopped state forever. Pretty much every app distributed through normal channels, including the Play Store, needs an activity.

> Does this mean that I have to put a spinner screen if checkSelfPermissions returns denied?

I do not know what "a spinner screen" is. AFAIK, the recommended pattern for a service needing a runtime permission that it does not have is to:

1. Raise a `Notification`, to let the user know that the service cannot do its work without this permission.
2. Have the `Notification` trigger an `Activity` that can call `requestPermissions()`. Optionally, this activity can have `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, so the only visible UI is the permission dialog.
3. If `onRequestPermissionResult()` indicates that you have the permission, the activity can tell the service to go ahead (e.g., via a call to `startService()`), then `finish()` itself. If `onRequestPermissionResult()` indicates that the user denied the permission, do whatever makes sense (e.g., show the `Notification` again, gracefully shut down, suggest to the user that the user uninstall the app).

Comment: Also, you must be aware that the user can turn off some permissions for the the app whenever he wants from the settings page.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am an OEM developer working on a pre-installed system app. The APK has no UI/Activity, it provides AIDL to other apps.