# AIDL Server ask permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions, aidl

I am using AIDL in my porject, I have two apk : AIDLServer and AIDLClient.

So far there is not Activity in AIDLServer(only has service), however, there are some operations need users' permission(just like Bluetooth, Location).

Under this situation, in Android 6 and above how can I get permission?(Adding a activity in AIDLServer is the only option?)

Comment: off-topic comment: Are you sure that you can run service from service only apk(apk without any Activity)? I'm pretty sure that it is not possible starting from some API number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far there is not Activity

AFAIK So it wont run.You should need an activity

> Android 6 and above how can I get permission?(Adding a activity in AIDLServer is the only option?)

Yes you have to add activity

Check this for reference answer service asking permission.Same you can use this AIDL

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817905/3505534

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a transparent activity. So for user, they can only see the permission ask Dialog